# Accepting all sorts of challenges that life offers is a pleasure ___ the brave

Tags: prepositions

> Accepting all sorts of challenges that life offers is a pleasure ___ the brave.

Which is the correct preposition to be used to fill the blank in above sentence ? Is it **to** or **for** ? I am confused between these two preposition as both sound fine to my ears.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more grammatical to say: "It's pleasure for us" than to say: "It's pleasure to us" for example.
We can say: "It's pleasure to meet you".
So the preposition *for* sounds more suitable than *to* in this case.

> Accepting all sorts of challenges that life offers is a pleasure for the brave.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 'for' sounds better.

Accepting all sorts of challenges that life offers is a pleasure ___ the brave.

I might consider these alternatives. This is something to think about; however,  your way is correct:

Accepting all sorts of challenges offered in life is a pleasure to the brave.

Accepting all sorts of challenges that life offers is a pleasure for the brave.

I just wanted to show you some contrast. I think that both of my examples are quite acceptable, but sometimes I make mistakes too and have to revisit my construction.